# displaying nested attributes in backgrid

Tags: backgrid

I have a json object in the following format:

```
{
    properties:{
                  url:"http://..."
               }
}
```

And I want to display the url in a Backgrid grid. However, I can't figure out how to change the name attribute of the column such that it accesses the nested url. I have tried the following examples to no avail:

```
{
    name: "properties.url",
    label: "URL",
    cell: "uri"
}
```

And

```
{
    name: "properties[url]",
    label: "URL",
    cell: "uri"
}
```

It seems like a simple enough thing to do but I can't find an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at Backbone's [Wiki](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/wiki/Extensions,-Plugins,-Resources#wiki-model).

There are at least 4 choices:

- [backbone-deep-model](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-deep-model)
- [backbone-nested](http://afeld.github.io/backbone-nested/)
- [backbone-nestify](http://revelytix.github.io/backbone-nestify/)
- [backbone-dotattr](https://github.com/amccloud/backbone-dotattr)

Answer (score 2):

This is the entireity of "backbone-dotattr"

```
(function(_, Backbone) {
    _.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype, {
        get: function(key) {
            return _.reduce(key.split('.'), function(attr, key) {
                if (attr instanceof Backbone.Model)
                    return attr.attributes[key];

                return attr[key];
            }, this.attributes);
        }
    });
})(window._, window.Backbone);
```

with this, i can specify

```
name: "child.childAttribute"
```

- works perfectly in the "columns" part for Backgrid. hope it helps.